# Dot division between pandas dataframe ignoring first column of one of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I have two pandas dataframes as follows:

```
df1_input = {'patient_id': [ABC], 'p1': [1], 'p2': [4], 'p3': [3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_input, columns=['patient_id', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3'])
```

df1 looks like:

```
patient_id   p1   p2   p3
    ABC      1    4    3

df2_input = {'feature': [p1, p2, p3], 'signals': [23, 45, 112]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_input, columns=['feature', 'signals']
```

df2 looks like:

```
feature   signals
   p1       23
   p2       45
   p3       112
```

I want to divide every number in df1 by its corresponding feature in df2, and return df1 again. Something like this:

```
patient_id   p1     p2      p3
   ABC      1/23   4/45    3/112
```

I have tried:

```
final = pd.DataFrame(df1.values / df2.values, index=df1.index, columns=df2.index)
```

But I get:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,4) (3,2)
```

The thing is: I cannot get rid of the patient_id column! Otherwise, I would not recognize where each number belongs to. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You could set indices: `df1.set_index('patient_id', inplace=True)` and `df2.set_index('feature', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) for align columns names with `feature` columns values:

```
df2 = df1.set_index('patient_id').div(df2.set_index('feature')['signals']).reset_index()
print (df2)
  patient_id        p1        p2        p3
0        ABC  0.043478  0.088889  0.026786
```

Comment: i went a little long, like this approach..+1

Answer (score 3):

use `loc` on df1 with columns of `df2.feature` and do inline division with ndarray of `df2.signals`

```
df1.loc[:, df2.feature] /= df2.signals.values

Out[229]:
  patient_id        p1        p2        p3
0        ABC  0.043478  0.088889  0.026786
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_df1 = df1.T.reset_index().rename({'index':'feature'},axis=1)
##temp_df1

      feature    0
0  patient_id  ABC
1          p1    1
2          p2    4
3          p3    3
```

---

```
temp_df1.merge(df2, how='outer').set_index('feature').apply(lambda x: x[0]/x['signals'] if str(x['signals']) !='nan' else x,axis=1).drop('signals',axis=1).T
```

**Output**

```
feature patient_id         p1         p2         p3
0              ABC  0.0434783  0.0888889  0.0267857
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try setting the indices? This should work for multiple features/signals too.

```
df1.set_index('patient_id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('feature', inplace=True)
```

**df1**

```
            p1  p2  p3
patient_id          
    ABC     1   4   3
```

**df2**

```
        signals
feature 
p1      23
p2      45
p3      112
```

then:

```
final = pd.DataFrame(df1.values / df2['signals'].values, index=df1.index, 
columns=df2.index)
```

Or even better, like in Jezraels [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57306711/7547749) with `div`:

```
final = df1.div(df2['signals'])
```

**final**

```
 feature        p1          p2          p3
 patient_id         
 ABC            0.043478    0.088889    0.026786
```